# Confusion about use of article before the word open

Tags: articles

I have a little doubt about use if article before the word open. Which one is correct in the following examples:
There exists an open interval. 
There exists a open interval.
 What is the rule?

Answer (score 1):

The correct option is

> There exists an open interval

Because **open** starts with a vowel.

Comment: What is the actual rule. We use  A University, not an university, please clarify @CowperKettle

Answer (score 0):

First one is still the better one:

> There exists an open interval

But i think you can should use:

> There is an existing open interval

Comment: You mean the first one, surely, not the second.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Oh sorry, edited my answer, thanks for correcting my stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

Which to use depends on whether the following word starts with a **vowel *sound***. "University" start with the y-consonant sound, so it's "a university", but "hour" starts with a vowel sound, so an "an hour". ***Interval*** also starts with a vowel sound, so it is "**an interval**".

If "university" were pronounced with an 'oo' sound, rather than a 'yoo' sound, it would use "an" as well.